# Email without ical event

Tags: php, html-email, email-attachments

I've got a problem with a email with a ical attachment. It works great when I send it with an ical attachment. But now I try to send the same mail without the attachment. When I remove all the ical code it still sends a mail but with an empty ical attachment. If I remove some more code it sends an empty message. I can't figure out what code to change to just remove the ical attachment. I would like to keep the email with and without the attachment the same.

Here is a picture of the attachment I keep seeing.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wetGu.png)

Could someone help me with this?

```
<?php

include ('../data/config.php');    
include('../data/conn.php');

$subject = $_POST['naam_opleiding'];  
$from_address   = $_POST['email_medewerker'];
$to_name   = $_POST['docent'];
$to_address   = $_POST['email_docent'];
$to_address2   = $_POST['email_medewerker'];
$to_cc   = $_POST['email_secretaresse'];
$startTime = $_POST['startTime'];        
$endTime = $_POST['endTime'];  
$aanhef = $_POST['aanhef']; 
$tekst = $_POST['tekst']; 
$college = $_POST['college']; 
$naam_opleiding = $_POST['naam_opleiding']; 
$datum = $_POST['datum']; 
$begintijd = $_POST['begintijd']; 
$eindtijd = $_POST['eindtijd']; 
$bedrag = $_POST['bedrag']; 
$reiskosten = $_POST['reiskosten']; 
$voornaam_medewerker = $_POST['voornaam_medewerker']; 
$medewerker = $_POST['medewerker']; 
$collegezaal = $_POST['collegezaal']; 
$doccol = $_POST['doccol']; 
$oplcol = $_POST['oplcol']; 

$domain = 'asreconnect.nl';

//Create Email Headers
$mime_boundary = "----Meeting Booking----".MD5(TIME());

$headers = "From: ".$medewerker." <".$from_address.">\n";
$headers .= "CC: ".$to_cc."\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$medewerker." <".$from_address.">\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$mime_boundary\"\n";
$headers .= "Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage\n";

//Create Email Body (HTML)
$message = "--$mime_boundary\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
$message .= "<html>\n";
$message .= "<body>\n";
$message .= '<p>Opleiding: <b>'.$naam_opleiding.'</b></p>';
$message .= '<p>College: <b>'.$college.'</b></p>';
$message .= '<p>Datum: <b>'.$datum.'</b> van <b>'.$begintijd.'</b> t/m <b>'.$eindtijd.'</b></p>';
$message .= '<p> '.$aanhef.' </p>';
$message .= '<p>'.$tekst.' </p>';
$message .= '<p>Alvast bedankt!</p>';
$message .= '<p>Hartelijke groet,</p>';
$message .= '<p>'.$voornaam_medewerker.'</p>';
$message .= "</body>\n";
$message .= "</html>\n";
$message .= "--$mime_boundary\r\n";

$ical = 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR' . "\r\n" .
'PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 10.0 MIMEDIR//EN' . "\r\n" .
'VERSION:2.0' . "\r\n" .
'METHOD:REQUEST' . "\r\n" .
'BEGIN:VTIMEZONE' . "\r\n" .
'TZID:CEST' . "\r\n" .
'BEGIN:STANDARD' . "\r\n" .
'DTSTART:20091101T020000' . "\r\n" .
'RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11' . "\r\n" .
'TZOFFSETFROM:+0000' . "\r\n" .
'TZOFFSETTO:+0200' . "\r\n" .
'TZNAME:EST' . "\r\n" .
'END:STANDARD' . "\r\n" .
'BEGIN:DAYLIGHT' . "\r\n" .
'DTSTART:20090301T020000' . "\r\n" .
'RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3' . "\r\n" .
'TZOFFSETFROM:-0000' . "\r\n" .
'TZOFFSETTO:+0200' . "\r\n" .
'TZNAME:EDST' . "\r\n" .
'END:DAYLIGHT' . "\r\n" .
'END:VTIMEZONE' . "\r\n" .  
'BEGIN:VEVENT' . "\r\n" .
'ORGANIZER;CN="'.$medewerker.'":MAILTO:'.$from_address. "\r\n" .
'ATTENDEE;CN="'.$to_name.'";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:'.$to_address. "\r\n" .
'LAST-MODIFIED:' . date("Ymd\TGis") . "\r\n" .
'UID:'.date("Ymd\TGis", strtotime($startTime)).rand()."@".$domain."\r\n" .
'DTSTAMP:'.date("Ymd\TGis"). "\r\n" .
'DTSTART;TZID="CEST":'.date("Ymd\THis", strtotime($startTime)). "\r\n" .
'DTEND;TZID="CEST":'.date("Ymd\THis", strtotime($endTime)). "\r\n" .
'TRANSP:OPAQUE'. "\r\n" .
'SEQUENCE:1'. "\r\n" .
'SUMMARY:' . $oplcol . "\r\n" .
'LOCATION:' . $collegezaal . "\r\n" .
'CLASS:PUBLIC'. "\r\n" .
'PRIORITY:5'. "\r\n" .
'BEGIN:VALARM' . "\r\n" .
'TRIGGER:-PT15M' . "\r\n" .
'ACTION:DISPLAY' . "\r\n" .
'DESCRIPTION:Reminder' . "\r\n" .
'END:VALARM' . "\r\n" .
'END:VEVENT'. "\r\n" .
'END:VCALENDAR'. "\r\n";
$message .= 'Content-Type: text/calendar;name="meeting.ics";method=REQUEST'."\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
$message .= $ical;

$mailsent = mail($to_address, $subject, $message, $headers);

return ($mailsent)?(true):(false);

?>
```

Comment: Commenting out `$message .= $ical;` still doesn't work?

Comment: No, that was one of the first things I tried. There still is a ical attachment visible. It should be something very simple, but I can't find the solution.

Comment: You need to remove all references to teh attachment(s) not just in message body but in message headers as well